# Set up VPN server around AP isolation

Tags: networking, server, ssh, network-manager, vpn

Here's my situation: I live at university housing where the internet has AP isolation. My friends and I (computer-science students) want to create a home server from some old computers we have. In particular, I'd like to be able to connect to them over SSH.

When I researched it online lots of websites suggested that a VPN would be the best way to get around the firewall/ap isolation. So, I got SoftEther and set it up on one of the home base pcs. It runs fine, so long as I'm connected to that computer through the network switch we set up. However, as soon as I switch over to wifi I'm no longer able to connect.

I have the server set up to a local ip address over ethernet, so obviously I won't be able to connect from a different wifi network. The local computer is at 10.158.102.203 and I'm able to ping it while connected to the wifi at 10.158.1.254 However, I can't connect over SSL-VPN.

Are there any ways to get this working? I do have access to a domain name and hosting server, so I was wondering if I could relay through that somehow. Or, is there a way to use part of SoftEther's VPN network as a relay? I know I can use a VPN to get unfiltered internet access to the local pc but I'm not sure that it will go both ways.

Hopefully someone here is cleverer than me!